# sql queries on ajax php page

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to get content inside a div using ajax, on the php page that am accessing using ajax, i want to fill dropdown options using another query but it just closes the select tag before the options.

```
<select class="form-control data" data-t="integer" name='role'  required/>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php

  foreach($con -> query("select id,name,permissions from role") as $role){
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $role['id']; ?>"><?php echo $role['name']; ?></option>
      <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

But here is what i get inside the div

```
<select class="form-control data" data-t="integer" name="role" 
required=""></select> 
<option value='1' >option1</option>
<option value='2' >option2</option>
<option value='3' >option3</option>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please remove forward `/` at the end of opening select tag as below:

```html
<select class="form-control data" data-t="integer" name='role'  required>
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php

  foreach($con -> query("select id,name,permissions from role") as $role){
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $role['id']; ?>"><?php echo $role['name']; ?></option>
      <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: oh snap! XD what the... XD sorry that was such an embarrassing mistake :D Btw... why did it work in the first place, i mean i used the same select (closed in the opening tag itself) on another page (not accessed by an ajax call). I just copied this dropdown from there.... it was working as required on that page, even with this error...